# which word has the higher chance? Maybe or possibly?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Both "**maybe**" and "**possibly**" can be used to express something might happen. I am wondering which word has the **higher** **chance**?

Comment: They are the same basically, it would depend on how it's spoken (inflection). **Probably** would be a higher chance than both of those.

Answer (score 2):

Neither one has a higher chance. See [possibly](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/possibly) and [maybe](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/maybe), and also [perhaps](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/perhaps). Also in Oxford ([maybe](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/maybe)).

Will you go to the new movie Friday?

perhaps
maybe
possibly

*Possibly* seems a bit more formal.

Also while you can say

*I'll possibly go*

saying

*I'll perhaps go*

is a bit weird, while

*I'll maybe go*

sounds really informal, if not uncouth.

Answer (score -1):

'Possible' contrasts with impossible: the focus is on reality and is there some conflict with reality.

'Maybe' places an answer between 'yes' and 'no' but does not specify where.

Because the two cannot be compared, there is no way to rank them on a mathematical scale of probability.

Comment: Saying that something "may be" (the origin of "maybe") literally just means that there is a chance of it. In other words, the same thing as "possible".

Answer (score -2):

There is no difference between the two.

However there is a very fine difference between **Maybe** and **Possibily**.

**Maybe** is used in informal context i.e When having a conversation with friends and family. Most people mistakenly use it with formal context which is absolutely wrong.

**Possibly** is used in formal context. 
It is best to use **Possibly** in your conversation as it provides a good structure,a polite request as in ***Could you possibly help me in my work?*** and also has the ability to describe the intensity/meaning of the situation.

**Quite Possibly/Very Possibly** expressions are used to indicate a greater possibility of something happening.

So it's better to stick with **Possibly** to give a better structure to your sentence.